# Blazor WASM authorize attribute based on query string

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

```
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = NavigationManager.QueryString("level"))]
```

I have added this code on my page level, the first authorize attribute works fine, since it is just a constant value "Admin" but not the second authorize attribute.

I am trying to grant access based on the query string, but this code `NavigationManager.QueryString("level")` will have this error
"An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0120)

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: You can do this with a policy. If I get time ill come back and write an answer. The policy name will be "Static" however you can write the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot do this. An attribute argument [needs to be a compile time constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25859203/9910440).

Long answer: don't do this. Checking for authorization using query string is inherently unsecure.

If you have complicated authorization, check out Policy based authorization.
[This](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/policy-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core-a-deep-dive/) is a good explainer in general. Check out [this](https://code-maze.com/blazor-webassembly-role-based-authorization/) for a more Blazor WASM specific example

Comment: oh, because this is just front end, it does not matter if its insecure, the backend is protected anyway

Comment: May be then you can just accept the query parameter and build logic around it? Say if("level"==something) then NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Login")?

Comment: on code level, I could do something like 
if ( !user.IsInRole(NavigationManager.QueryString("level")) ) { someUnauthorizedProcess() }

I have a <AuthorizeRouteView> for <NotAuthorized> display, but I don't know how to make it display <NotAuthorized> in code level.

Comment: Just create a razor component and use it 1) under <NotAuthorized> and 2) another page (say "/NotAuthorized")

Comment: can I display NotAuthorized without changing URL? means it will still stay on same URL showing that component

Comment: You can use similar logic https://stackoverflow.com/a/69609157/9910440