# Return 404 In Blazor Server Page

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages

I'm trying to migrate a Razor Pages app to a Blazor Server app as part of a staged migration (rather than big bang).  I'm currently moving a relatively straight forward CRUD set of pages.  These pages have a typical route strucutre like...

```
/entity/
/entity/edit/{id}
/entity/detail/{id}
/entity/delete/{id}
```

In a razor page for 'edit' I would typically have an OnGetAsync method that accepts the id as a parameter, searches for the entity using the id and returns the page.  However, if the id is not a valid entity my OnGet would return NotFound (IActionResult).  What I'm trying to figure out is how I would do that with a Blazor Server page/component.

My blazor page looks like this (just the relevant bits)

```
@page "/entity/edit/{id:int}"
...
@code {
    [Parameter] public int Id { get; set; }
    public Entity Model { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        Model = await SomeServiceCall.GetAsync(Id);
        if(Model == null)
            return; // TODO: Return 404 rather than the page
    }
}
```

How do I tell Blazor to return 404?  So that my  is displayed rather than my page?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69609157/21429) appears to offer a solution.

Answer (score -2):

There is App.razor file in your project

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Look at  section, when Blazor do not find path being navigated it displays html present this section, so you can replace this line with information you want to display then

```
 <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
```

Comment: That only applies if the route doesn't exist.  In this instance I need to run some code before I can confirm that the route does not exist.  e.g. "/entity/edit/1" is a real entity and a correct route, "/entity/edit/50001" is a valid route, but there is no record with that id so the page should return "Not Found"

Comment: Could you please explain a bit, where do you want to return 404, If the id you are looking for is not found then you can conditionally render the html you want in the same page